# Prove the extension to be a Galois Extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Let $p$ be a prime number. $K$=$\mathbb C(x,y)$ and $F=\mathbb C(x^p,y^p)$.Then, Prove that $K/F$ is a Galois Extension.

Trial:

Since this $\mathbb C$ is a field of charactersitic $0$,it would be enough to show that $K$ is a splitting field of some separable polynomial.
My guess is that the polynomial $f(t)=(t^p-x^p)(t^p-y^p)$.But i am not able to prove K is the splitting field of $f(t)$.
Is this the right way and logic?

Comment: Maybe see what are the roots of $t^{p}-x^{p}$. $x$ is a root, so
$t-x\mid t^{p}-x^{p}$ so you can divide and see what are the other
roots..maybe all are easily seen to be in $K$

Comment: @belgi What we get aft doing that is $t^{p-1} + t^{p-2}x+......+x^{p-1}$.I am not able to see its roots or if it splits in K.

Comment: tiny nitpick: you definitely don't need to exhibit an irreducible polynomial of which $K$ is the splitting field; any separable polynomial is fine. (in particular, your polynomial is obviously not irreducible over F, but that's fine)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the suggested polynomial $f = (t^p - x^p)(t^p - y^p)\in \mathbb C(x^p,y^p)[t]$ does the job.
Let $L$ be its splitting field.

Since $x$ and $y$ are roots of $f$, clearly $K \subseteq L$.

The full set of roots of $f$ is given by all $\zeta^i x$ and $\zeta^i y$ where $\zeta\in\mathbb C$ is a primitive $p$th root of unity and $i\in\{0,\ldots,p-1\}$.
Since $x,y\in K$ and $\zeta\in\mathbb C\subseteq K$, all the roots of $f$ are contained in $K$ and thus $L\subseteq K$.

This shows $K = L$, so $K$ is the splitting field of $f$.